# SQL Server 2005 Down or Unavailable History

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005

I have a SQL Server 2005 instance which has a nightly run SSIS Job. sometimes in the morning I see the report generated by SQL Job that the Server was unavailable.

Error:

> Error code: 0x80004005. An OLE DB record is available.
>   Source: "Microsoft SQL Server Native Client 10.0" Hresult: 0x80004005 Description: "Login timeout expired".
>   An OLE DB record is available. Source: "Microsoft SQL Server Native Client 10.0" Hresult: 0x80004005
>   Description: "A network-related or instance-specific error has occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. Server is not found or not accessible. Check if instance name is correct and if SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections.

When I connect to instance in the morning, I can see that it is working fine now.

Is there someway to find out two things.

1. When it was down and back up again
2. What's the reason of down.

Thanks

Comment: Have you checked the error logs?

Comment: For SSIS packages, I checked the error log and it says that the server was not available. I want to get back to IT to tell them that the server was down from this time till this time.

Comment: Sorry for lack of specifics. In my experience this error is either network / firewall, sql browser not running, or SQL instance is down. SQL instance error logs can help.